# How to use a Toggle Switch in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, toggle

I have a toggle with in my php that I would like to use to simply change a value in a mysql table.  Far as I know, it is simply an element of a form, but how can I POST that ON/OFF value just by switching, without using a 'submit' method?

```
 <input data-no-uniform="true" type="checkbox" class="iphone-toggle">
```

for now it is an input element with fancy CSS to make this checkbox into a slide switch. SO if the switch has a default state and simply sliding the switch or "checking the box" would be enough to change the value in a cell.  where is the submission in that?

Hope that makes sense....

Comment: You need ajax for that. Are you using a javascript library?

Comment: Yes actually I am using a js/jquery.iphone.toggle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, you can do something like:

```
$('.iphone-toggle').on('change', function() {
  var toggle_data = $(this).data('no-uniform')
      toggle_value = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'your_url.php',
    data: {toggle: toggle_data, value: toggle_value},
    success: function() {
      // what you do on success
    }
  });
});
```

And in php you will have the values of `$_POST['toggle']` and `$_POST['value']` to make the correct database query.

Comment: shouldn't I be using an id or a name to ref the toggle switch?   <input data-no-uniform="true" type="checkbox" class="iphone-toggle" name="toggle">

Comment: @user3399760 I assumed that the `data` attribute uniquely identified the checkbox, but you can use an id or the name if that is not the case.

Comment: thanks for the advice guy.  This will set me in the right direction.